# Different response from Spotify API when calling endpoints from Javascript vs REST client

Tags: javascript, rest, post

I'm working on implementing some Spotify calls into a project using the Spotify API and the first thing I have to do is authenticate. I tested out the Spotify API endpoint by using Restlet (a REST API client) and my call is successful with the response of:

> { "access_token":
>   "BQC2PbOsWsnkfzcMUMW5YeJh9VGgE7uSQ-ubpO5kekyn3IIq0yVqoIW6Rx-5sQLJyH8R8wik6PzcFfzFDCU",
>   "token_type": "Bearer", "expires_in": 3600, "scope": "" }

I then implemented the POST call in my React app using javascript and it worked!

```
async function getSpAccessToken(component) {
    const [initSpotResponse] = await Promise.all([
        axios.post("https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
            querystring.stringify({
                grant_type: 'client_credentials'
            }),
            {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Basic ${encodedString}`,
                    'Content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                }
            }
        ).catch((error) => {
            console.log("getSpAccessToken ERROR = " + JSON.stringify(error))
        })
    ]);
    const spAccessToken = await initSpotResponse.data.access_token 

}
```

But eventually when the token expires, my calls to Spotify respond with a "access_token expired" message, as expected. I go back and re-authenticate using the same `getSpAccessToken()` function but I get this as a response:

```
{
  "data": "",
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {},
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Basic ZmY1NmFiZTc3OTJmNDI2ZWE0MWE3NzFkNzA3ZDY2OTaA6YjJjY2EyZGVkZDM5NDliMGE2YzVlMTU4MjQ0NmM5YzU="
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    "data": "grant_type=client_credentials"
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

The response is confusing because a) the status code is OK and b) because the `data` field is empty (this is where the access token resides). I then try to use my REST client, Restlet, to try the same call again and I get an access_token in my response! Then I go back and refresh my page and my `getSpAccessToken()` function gets called and this time it returns a data object:

```
{
  "data": {
    "access_token": "BQCuvTWeJlixkOsuAhKPClKWaXTaSPiuycNY6Z2EKKQLqsDyGyXdDcn4RR4tVq6--1HHJ_l1ViDlCi_mN_bk",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600,
    "scope": ""
  },
  "status": 200,
  "statusText": "OK",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json"
  },
  "config": {
    "transformRequest": {},
    "transformResponse": {},
    "timeout": 0,
    "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
    "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
    "maxContentLength": -1,
    "headers": {
      "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "Authorization": "Basic ZmY1NmFiZTc3OTJmNDI2ZWE0MWE3NzFkNzA3ZDY2OaTA6YjJjY2EyZGVkZDM5NDliMGE2YzVlMTU4MjQ0NmM5YzU="
    },
    "method": "post",
    "url": "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token",
    "data": "grant_type=client_credentials"
  },
  "request": {}
}
```

My question: Why is it that when I need to refresh my token, my javascript `getSpAccessToken()` call returns a response with an empty `data` field until after I use my REST client to make that same call?

Comment: Have you tried the whole thing without using the REST client at all? Or does it only work if you start out that way to get a token? Javascript is notorious for not being able to call APIs due to CORS issues

Comment: I want to say it is a CORS issue, like @Bman70 hints at.  For refreshing a token, I had to make the request server-side.

Comment: this is a CORS issue - you need to make the call from a server or emulation of a server